# How to make entity framework respect the true nature of default values on DB columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

Consider the following table definition which creates a table with default values which are not nullable and which have default values for when a value is not supplied

```
drop table [defaultTest]

CREATE TABLE [defaultTest](
    [TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestData] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TestKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TestTimeStamp] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TestId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [defaultTest] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Test_TestKey]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [SomeSequence]) FOR [TestKey]
GO

ALTER TABLE [defaultTest] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Test_TestTimeStamp]  DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()) FOR [TestTimeStamp]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [defaultTest_TestKey_Insert_UK] ON [defaultTest]
(
    [TestKey] ASC,
    [TestTimeStamp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

declare @testkey int;
declare @id int;
insert into [defaultTest]([TestData]) values ('Original');
set @id = @@IDENTITY;
select @testkey = [TestKey] from [defaultTest] where [TestId] = @id;
insert into [defaultTest]([TestData], [TestKey] ) values ('Updated', @testkey);

select * from [defaultTest];

TestId  TestData    TestKey TestTimeStamp
1   Original    27  2019-06-26 14:40:22.1042605 +10:00
2   Updated 27  2019-06-26 14:40:22.1062673 +10:00
```

In the database this works perfectly. An insert can supply a value or not and the database will ensure that a value is always there.

But when this database table is referenced in entity framework database first i'm struggling to get entity framework to respect the true nature of the situation.

Observed behaviour is that it  will either **always** pass zero values if StoredGeneratedPattern = none and the fields are empty and **always** pass null if StoredGeneratedPattern = Computed (or Identity) even if a value is supplied.

That is not how the definition ever works at the database level so why entity framework was programmed that way is a mystery?

Is there a way to get entity framework to behave properly for this scenario?

EDIT: I tried removing the not null constraint from the Key but entity framework refuses to pull the generated value back from the database.

Comment: This is interesting.  Did you ever resolve your problem?

Comment: No and it's not likely it ever will be. It's harsh for me to say it but having spent the last few years working with sql server after having worked with other databases for 15+ years prior it's clear that Microsoft despite being very good at many things (not counting Windows 10) they've never been that great with databases. Something like this would never be thought of as something they would need to cater for. The visual studio team (or whoever develops entity framework) just doesn't understand that databases are the critical heart of an application and not just a simple storage bucket.

Comment: So much of what M$ does seems to try to de-emphasize the database.  But if the database is done correctly, it make the rest of the project so much easier.  I've never understood the fear developers seem to have with database design.  I was taught DB first, get it right, then you can start coding.  But I came up in a full stack shop.